# Solution to a differential equation in terms of Bessel function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I am looking after the solution of the following differential equation:

$
\partial_y \partial_y \psi + \frac{\partial_y \psi}{y} + \left( \frac{\omega^2 }{y^2} - \frac{\Lambda}{y} \right) \psi = 0
$

where both $\omega$ and $\Lambda$ are constants.

I know *cough, Mathematica, cough * that the solution to this should be given in terms of (Modified) Bessel functions. However I am having a really hard time trying to show this.

As usual, I tried a variable change with a free parameter $P$ as:

$\psi(y) = \Psi(x)$ with $x=y^P$

where

$\frac{d \psi}{dy} = \frac{d \Psi(x)}{dx} \frac{dx}{dy} = \Psi' P y^{P-1}$

to get

$\Psi'' + y^{-P} \Psi' + \left( \frac{\omega^2}{P^2} y^{-2P} - \frac{\Lambda}{P^2} y^{-2P+1} \right) \Psi=0$

where, usually, we can choose a suitable $P$ to make this equation resemble a special function. However I cannot see anything from here.

How do I solve it, or make it resemble something Bessel-like?